Is there any way to achieve image translation similar to google lens using the google cloud API?
I've been working on a Firefox extension that will allow users to right click an image to translate it to their default language. Google's cloud vision & translate APIs works great for this, aside from one thing. If you go to the google translate website and upload an image for translation, you get an image with the text actually overwritten in your selected language.
Before
After
I can only find resources online for extracting text from images, not actually overwriting the text on the image itself. The best I can seem to do is get the bounding boxes of text locations on the image.
Is there any way to get the same result above using the vision/translate APIs (or possibly other ones), or do I have to handle the overlaying of the new text to the image?

If you have the bounding box, the rest is pretty easy, right?  pillow can do that.

@TimRoberts I know there's probably a good number of solutions to draw the new text over the old one on the image, more just wondering if there's a preexisting all-in-one solution where I just hand off an image and the language to be translated and Google handles the rest. I will take a look at implementing it through pillow though
